# 3 button Jquery on/off and both on/off

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 buttons: button 1, button 2 and button 3. button 1 toggles show/hide of the left side. button 2 does the same but does the right side. Button 3 does both sides. What is the right way to do this?

https://jsfiddle.net/anthony0perez/m9h2n1vk/2/

```
<div id="list-map-button" class="btn map-btn">LIST</div>
<div id="map-map-button" class="btn map-btn">MAP</div>
<div id="both-map-button" class="btn map-btn map-btn-active">BOTH</div>
<br style="clear:both;"/>
<div class="container">
    <div id="left_side">
        map side
        <div  id="block-3">Block 3</div>
        <div id="block-4" class="not-active-block">Block 4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="right_side">
        list side
        <div id="block-5">Block 5</div>
        <div id="block-6" class="not-active-block">Block 6</div>
    </div>
    <br style="clear:both;"/>
</div>

    $(document).ready(function(){    
    $( "#both-map-button" ).click(function() {
        //alert('clicked both button');
        $("#block-4, #block-3, #block-5, #block-6").hide();
        $("#block-4, #block-3, #block-5, #block-6").addClass("acvite-btn");

        $("#block-4, #block-3").show();
        $("#block-5, #block-6").show();

    });
    $( "#map-map-button" ).click(function() {
        //alert('clicked map button');
        $("#block-5").toggle();
        $("#block-6").toggle();
    });
    $( "#list-map-button" ).click(function() {
         //alert('clicked list button');
        $("#block-4").toggle();
        $("#block-3").toggle();
    });
 });
```

Comment: What is the right way to do what? What have you tried so far?

Comment: I have tried having each button on click then show hide content. The issue I am running into is that if the there is 2 buttons for show/hide each side then if you have the both show and hide one is going to toggle wrong.

Comment: I suggest adding this information to the question and the relevant code.

Comment: So removing and adding blocks based on buttons. As you can see when you click the both remove 4 and 5 and leave the other 2. Just like when you click on the map and list button from the beggining. Granted if you click the both button first it won't work at all the way I want it to. First try it list and map then the both button should do the same but not all 4 blocks just switch the 2.

Comment: Flagging this question as off-topic because it is unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question to clarify exactly what is going wrong and what you want.

Comment: How is it off topic? All I am looking to do is toggle between pieces content from 2 buttons. Done that. The other thing I wanted to do is toggle between the 2 sides at the same time with a both button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use a single variable to hold your state. Note that I hard-coded the loops for the example since we're always dealing with three buttons.

```js
inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
state = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    inputs[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      state ^= (i + 1);
      for (var j = 1; j < 3; j++) {
        inputs[j - 1].classList.toggle('on', (j & state));
      }
    });
  }(i));
}
```

```css
input {
  background: lightgray
}
input.side {
  background: red
}
input.on {
  background: limegreen
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="side" value="toggle left" />
<input type="button" class="side" value="toggle right" />
<input type="button" value="toggle both" />
```

If you're instead looking to turn both toggles on if one is already on, you can simply add a separate check for that.

```
if (i & 2) {
    state = ~~(state > 0) * 3;
}
```